# detect the first character in a variable c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a program that reads in serial information from a device and that works fine but i want to make a statement something like;
if (first character = R)
do something
if (first character = T)
do something else

I hope this makes sense. Basically all i need to do is have a way to detect the first character from a variable, then remove that character from the variable.

Thanks

Comment: This also seems like a homework question.  Honestly its to simple, and your questions seem to be "I have no idea how to do this" type questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming we are talking about a string:

```
string input = GetInput();
string remainingPart = input.Substring(1); // get string without first character
switch (input[0])
{
    case 'R':
        {
            DoSomething(remainingPart);
            break;
        }
    case 'T':
        {
            DoSomethingElse(remainingPart);
            break;
        }
    // more case clauses follow here
    default:
        {
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it a string variable? Then you can easily access it's first character:

```
string mystring = ...
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mystring))
{
  char first = mystring[0];
  // ...

  string withoutFirst = mystring.Substring(1);
  // ...
}
```

Comment: that would be perfect. how would i then save that variable without the first character?

Comment: extended my answer, see also [here in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[`String.StartsWith()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw.aspx) : Determines whether the beginning of this string instance matches the specified string.
[`String.Substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx) : Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read char and discard it, then I suggest that it is better for you to use Queue.

First, split the string into characters and queue it into a Queue. And then dequeue each item in the queue and process it as required.